# Command Rubocop not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am building a Ruby app and when I try to run linters using the command `rubocop` in the VS Code terminal I get this error:

```
Command 'robocop' not found, did you mean:
  command 'rubocop' from deb rubocop (0.89.1+dfsg-3)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

I had installed rubocop using the command `gem install rubocop` so I don't think it's an issue with installation. When I run the code `sudo apt install rubocop`, and then run the `rubocop` command in the terminal I get the following error:

```
(/home/tobuya/Projects/School_Library/.rubocop.yml): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 1 column 1
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych.rb:456:in `parse_stream'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/psych.rb:390:in `parse'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/lib/rubocop/yaml_duplication_checker.rb:12:in `check'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:215:in `check_duplication'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:63:in `load_yaml_configuration'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:43:in `load_file'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/lib/rubocop/config_loader.rb:104:in `configuration_from_file'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/lib/rubocop/config_store.rb:68:in `for_dir'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/lib/rubocop/config_store.rb:47:in `for_pwd'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:145:in `parallel_by_default!'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:49:in `block in run'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:77:in `profile_if_needed'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/lib/rubocop/cli.rb:43:in `run'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/exe/rubocop:19:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/3.0.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rubocop-1.48.1/exe/rubocop:19:in `<top (required)>'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/rubocop:23:in `load'
/home/tobuya/.rbenv/versions/3.0.1/bin/rubocop:23:in `<main>'
```

I am new to Ruby as you can see from the project I am trying to build and I would really appreciate any help and suggestions on this. I have struggled with this for over 3 hrs and I really need help. Thank you guys and I am looking forward to someone helping me out

`gem install rubocop`

Comment: You typed in `robocop` **instead of** `rubocop`.

Comment: Thank you for that observation. When I use `rubocop` I am getting the second error shown above

Comment: Can you show the code where you made the `rubocop` call? Its hard to decode what happened with just an error code.

Comment: When I run the code `rubocop` in the terminal, I get the above error. The second error shown above

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet, any help is pretty much appreciated.

Comment: What does the `.rubocop.yml` file look like. Seems like you might have invalid YAML

Comment: Hi! I would recommend showing us your complete terminal session, including directory changes. That is: open a terminal, navigate to your desired directory, install Rubocop, invoke rubocop. That should help us diagnose.

Comment: Also please add the contents of your `.rubocop.yml` to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [installation documentation](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop-rails#installation) and successfully installed and used `rubocop`. As per the documentation, this is how you install it:

```
gem install rubocop-rails
```

To use it on the terminal:

```
rubocop --require rubocop-rails
```

Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop-rails/) that tells you how to use `rubocop`.